# Vue-tables-2 - setting up initial filtering

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-tables-2

I'm using [vue-tables-2](https://github.com/matfish2/vue-tables-2) for my Vue.js app and I'm wondering if there is a possibility to set up (programatically) default (initial) filters that are applied once table is rendered?

I would like to avoid finding that DOM's element and firing click element on that dropdown to set up those filters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `initFilters` option.
See documentation [here](https://matanya.gitbook.io/vue-tables-2/options-api)